# How to use the container std::array<type, size> for multidimensional array in c++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array

An one dimensional array, e.g., containing three integers can be defined either as `std::array<int, 3> myarray` or `myarray[3]`. Is there a container like `std::array<type, size>` for a multidimensional array like `myarray[3][3]`?

Comment: `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>`

Comment: If you only ever use arrays of the same size, it might be a good idea to use a few typedefs: `using Row = std::array<int, 3>; using Matrix = std::array<Row, 5>;` for example.

Comment: @AntonSavin: That is an _answer_. Why are you posting a comment with the answer in it? Question comments are for requesting clarification and pointing out problems with the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://ideone.com/EdMHc5) should work:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size, std::size_t ...Sizes>
struct MultiArray : public std::array<MultiArray<T, Sizes...>, Size>
{
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct MultiArray<T, Size> : public std::array<T, Size>
{
};

int main()
{
    MultiArray<int, 3, 6, 8> ma;

    std::cout << ma.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << ma[0].size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << ma[0][0].size() << std::endl;

    ma[2][1][6] = 4;
}
```

Comment: The downside is that `MultiArray` is no longer an aggregate.

Answer (score 4):

A key part is making sure that `{}` initialization works like `std::array`, and keeping yourself as pod-like as reasonable.  Compatibility with `std::array` is also important, and what is more compatible than a `std::array`?  So my solution generates the multi dimensional array out of `std::array`s:

```
template<class T, size_t... sizes>
struct multi_array_helper {
  using type=T;
};
template<class T, size_t... sizes>
using multi_array = typename multi_array_helper<T, sizes...>::type;

template<class T, size_t s0, size_t... sizes>
struct multi_array_helper<T, s0, sizes...> {
  using type=std::array<multi_array<T, sizes...>, s0>;
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc826a892508b814)

Sample syntax:

```
multi_array<int, 2,2> arr = {{ {{0,1}}, {{2,3}} }};
static_assert( std::is_same< multi_array<int,2,2>, std::array<std::array<int,2>,2> >{}, "see, just arrays under the hood" );
```

A slight optimization might involve collapsing the entire array heirarchy if anything has a dimension of 0, but I'm unsure.

A `multi_array<int>` is an `int` as an aside (zero-dimensional array of `int`s), both because it makes sense, and because it makes the code simpler.

---

Here is an [old version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ccb54ff2055e8bf).